# Не могу вызвать await функцию из __init__

Tags: python, asyncio

0

bot.py:

```
import asyncio
import async_bot_api
from util import User

bot = new_bot()
user = User()

async def get_username(id):
    return await bot.get_username()

#bot logic

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(bot.run())
loop.run_forever()
```

util.py:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        self.username = await get_username()

from bot import get_username()
```

Не получается вызвать метод get_username(). В настоящем коде он чуть сложнее чем здесь. Возможно код плохой, исправьте меня пожалуйста.

Comment: Что значит "Не получается вызвать"? Возникает какая-то ошибка? Приведите ошибку вместе с [mre] в вопросе с помощью кнопки править

Comment: При запуске этого кода происходит ошибка          

SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function.         

async к методу __init__ добавлять нельзя.         

Нужно как то запускать через loop из bot.py, но я не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Почему бы вместо корутины `get_username` не написать корутину `get_user`, которая вернет готовый к использованию объект `User` со всеми заполненными полями?